# android java regex named groups

Tags: android, regex, regex-group

I would like to use

```
matcher.group("login");
```

In android 8+ on eclipse, but no Matcher.group(String) seems to exist.
Have you got a (built in) solution ?

Comment: Matcher doesn't work that way. Show us what you want to get from which String

Comment: I would like this form of regex: (?<login>X)

Comment: The regex is from a config file that's why i need named groups

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Android [`Pattern`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class implementation is provided by ICU, to be precise, [ICU4C](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp).

> The regular expression implementation used in Android is provided by [ICU](http://www.icu-project.org/). The notation for the regular expressions is mostly a superset of those used in other Java language implementations. This means that existing applications will normally work as expected, but in rare cases Android may accept a regular expression that is not accepted by other implementations.

And ICU4C currently doesn't support named capturing group. You have to fall back on numbered capturing groups.

> ICU does not support named capture groups. http://bugs.icu-project.org/trac/ticket/5312

You need to write a wrapper and parse the expression yourself to provide named capturing group capability, if you really need the feature.

Answer (score 6):

I thought I should share a solution I found. There is a fantastic library available on Github written by Tony Trinh (tony19) that enables one to use named regex groups.

Taken from the project page:

"This lightweight library adds support for named capture groups in Java 5/6 (and on Android).

This is a fork of the named-regexp project from Google Code (currently inactive)."

https://github.com/tony19/named-regexp

I've just tested this on Android 4.1.1 and above, and so far it's working like a charm. I was pleasantly surprised to find that I could simply replace my imports for Matcher and Pattern with the classes from this library, and all of my existing regexes that still used numbered groups still worked.

I hop this helps.

Comment: Hi, how to embed this library in android project?

Comment: I figured it out, I added depending `implementation 'com.github.tony19:named-regexp:0.2.6'`